# How to increment months loop. Then display from then

Tags: c++, loops, counter

Hell everyone ! I'm a noob to programming. I've tried to search something similar to what I'm looking for but I can't fully understand similar examples.

What I'm trying to do is have an user input a number of years, convert years to months. Then display from month 1 to full amount of months in a list while using the months variable. I need the loop to continue until it reaches the the full amount of months, then stop there. Below is what I know so far and what I've learned. I suspect that I may need to use some type of counter variable but not exactly sure how to do it.

```
int main(){
int years, months;
printf("Enter years ");
scanf_s("%d", &years);

months = years * 12;
printf("Months is %d ", months); 

do {
    printf("Month", ); //Month 1,2,3,4........24 up to full amount that was converted from years//
} while ();
return 0;
```

Comment: Use an auxiliar variable to mantain the amount of months you have already displayed. In the loop iterate until months reaches 0 by decrementing its value.

Comment: do {
    printf("%d, ", counter);
    months--;
while(months != 0);

Comment: Thanks ! I tried decrementing before but didn't know how to turn it around in order.

Comment: Added an answer below with a link so you can look at how loops work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int count = 1;
while (month != 0) {
   printf("%d, ", count);
   month = month - 1;
   count = count + 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I finally got the proper result! I will examine this thoroughly to use this experience in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at loops, while, for and do-while. Here is a link to a simple and direct tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_loops.htm

For your problem just create an extra variable initialized with 1 and loop until it passes the value of months.

```
int years = 0;
int months = 0;
int counter = 1;

printf("Enter years ");
scanf("%d", &years);

months = years * 12;
printf("Months is %d ", months);

printf("Months: ");

do {
    printf("%d ", counter); //Month 1,2,3,4........24 up to full amount that was converted from years//
    counter++;
} while (counter <= months);

return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! I wasn't aware that I could initialize the years, months etc. That's the main reason why I was having trouble. I  copied your code and tweaking it to implement it with other variables.

Comment: Always initialize your variables! Even pointers - with NULL. Hope you learn a lot with the community. Have a good day.

Comment: Yes, I couldn't edit but meant to say initialize with = 0 . Sure looking forward to learn and contribute.